# Why is my VC displaced after changing the Simulator? AutoLayout

Tags: swift, view, autolayout, constraints

Hey this is the code I use to set the constraints with auto layout for my View Elements:

```
TimeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
               
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
               TimeLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
               TimeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: -30),
               TimeLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
               TimeLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
    
    ])
```

But it doesn't work! When I change the simulator from iPhone 11 to iPhone 11 Pro, I can't see some of my elements because the whole VC is displaced!

What can I do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide a little more detail. In the code you posted, you have set `TimeLabel` Top to be 30-pts ***above*** the Top of the view. Is that what you want?

Comment: Also, an iPhone 11 view has a Height of 896 ... an iPhone 11 Pro view has a Height of 812. Are you laying out your UI elements to be a total of 896-pts in Height?

Comment: Okay Bro thank you but could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: More specific? You didn't answer either of my questions. I have no way of being more specific without knowing what you are doing, or what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okay look, I'm really new at this area and at the moment I'm working on my first app and all the view elements are good positioned when I use iPhone 11. Like the ```TimeLabel``` is placed there where it should be with the codes I posted upstairs. But when I change the device, the element is displaced and some of my elements are actually invisible! So what I need is the knowledge about what I can change about my code to position it all at the same. Equal which device I use

Comment: I realize you are new... but it's very difficult to help someone who won't answer simple questions. Regardless, I posted an answer guessing at what you may be running into. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Particularly because you are, as you say, *"really new at this area"* - I ***strongly*** suggest that you spend some time learning about Auto-layout and adapting to screen sizes.

Start with Apple's docs, and then search for tutorials... you'll find an abundance of them.

But, to maybe help you start to understand, look at these two examples (you'll want to open them in new browser tabs/windows to get a good look):

**Example 1**

[image]

As you can see, I've given each UI element a Height constraint, and then, starting at the top, 40-pts of vertical space constraints between each.

Looks fine on an iPhone 11, but since an 11 Pro is shorter, the **Fourth Label** has been pushed off the bottom of the screen.

**Example 2**

[image]

The layout looks very similar, expect I embedded the UI elements in a `UIStackView`. I then constrained the stack view Top and Bottom, and set its `Distribution` property to `Equal Spacing`.

Now, with the shorter 11 Pro, the *spacing between the elements* is decreased, and we can still see the **Fourth Label**.

---

There is a whole lot more to it than this. For example, what happens when we rotate the device? What happens when we run on a 12.9" iPad Pro?

But, maybe, hopefully, this can give you a starting point.

Comment: Okay so the best way to do what I want is to use a StackView instead of auto layouts? I really tried to find good tutorials about autoLayouts but they are all working with Storyboard, I want to learn it all programmatically, that make it harder but I'm sure I will accomplish:)

Comment: @EasyChris - *"the best way to do what I want is to use a StackView instead of auto layouts?"* --- no. Stack Views are ***part of auto-layout***. This is just a simple example of *one way* to manage different screen sizes. Go through a dozen or so tutorials about auto-layout. Doesn't matter if they use Storyboard - the ideas are the same. Learn about auto-layout / trait-variations / using constraint multipliers as percentages / etc. Once you are familiar with how it works, it's straightforward to implement in code instead of Storyboards. But ya gotta learn it first.